# I would like the filtering below to be case-sensitive, i.e. when I write ABC it would not display aBc, etc

Tags: android

In the code below the filtering is not case-sensitive. I would like the filtering would be case-sensitive, for example when I write ABC in my app it would not ALSO display aBc, Abc, aBc, abC and abc:

```
private ListView lv;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

EditText inputSearch;


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String products[] = {"ABC", "abc", "aBc", "Abc", "abC"
```

};

```
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: you need some custom adapter like: `class Adapter extends` [MatchableArrayAdapter](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0)`<String> { ...` and override its `matches` method

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can try this 

inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()));   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        }
    });
```